# Tkinter Background Image Won't Load

Tags: python, image, tkinter, background

I'm trying to create a class called Game where once it's called already has attributes like the background image and such. The problem is that Tkinter won't load the background image with the following code and I cannot figure out why.

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, height=600, width=600)
        root.title('Hangman')
        root.minsize(600, 600)
        root.maxsize(600, 600)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.background_image = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='D:\Python\Projects\Hangman\Images\Platform_3.png')
        self.background_label = tkinter.Label(root, image=self.background_image)
        self.background_label.place(relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.3, anchor='nw')
```

Comment: Post your main loop that initiates `Game` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the path. The slashes are messing it up.

You can solve it by:
**Replacing the backward slashes with the forward slashes**. For example:
`"D:/Python/Projects/Hangman/Images/Platform_3.png"`

**Using `r` behind the string** (`r` means the string will be treated as raw string <sub>Google</sub>) . For example:
 `r"D:\Python\Projects\Hangman\Images\Platform_3.png"`

**Using Double Backward slashes instead of one**. For example:
`"D:\\Python\\Projects\\Hangman\\Images\\Platform_3.png"`

Comment: Yeah, that seemed to fix it.  What is it about the path the causes this?  Just curious so I don't encounter this problem in the future.  Thank you, btw!

Comment: @KennethBectell Several combinations of letters with `\ ` can result in unicode. For example, `\n` newline

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a variable and save a reference for it. Like this:

```
add = PhotoImage(file="icons/add.png")
label = Label(image=add)
label.image = add  # keep a reference!
```

and then:

```
AddButton = Button(MOWindow, image=add, border="0", bg="white", command=AddCallback)
```